# ASP literal not working

Tags: asp.net, literals

I am trying to get an asp: literal to work but apparently I am doing something wrong because I am getting an

> Object Referece not set to an instance
>   of the Object

error

This is my code:

in the ascx page:

```
<span class="span1">
   <asp:Literal ID="litFile" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <strong><asp:Literal ID="litFile2" runat="server"></asp:Literal></strong>
</span>
```

and

in the ascx.cs page:

```
protected void _ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litFile")).Text = "a";
}
```

Any idea please?

C

Comment: Can you show us more code? Is this literal in a grid? What event handler are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 1):

We need more code to know for sure, but what this looks like to me is that the literal is actually outside the repeater that's firing the `_ItemBound` method. Otherwise, `e.Item.FindControl` should be able to find it. Make sure `litFile` is inside the `ItemTemplate` in your repeater control, rather than elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to cast it, nor should you need to search for it.

Try just:

```
litFile.Text = "a";
```

If this doesn't work, we will need to see more code to work out what's going on.

Comment: If it's in a repeater, he'll need to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using FindControl I assume your in a repeater or something, so try this

```
Literal litFile = repeaterName.FindControl("litFile");
litFile.text = "a";
```

I code in VB so sorry if my syntax is off.

Comment: Couple of issues: The Literal would have to be inside one of the repeater's templates (itemtemplate, headertemplate, etc.), so the `FindControl` method would have to come from `repeaterName.HeaderTemplate` or the `e.Item` from the event handler, which would be equivalent to what he posted. You also need an explicit cast (the `(Literal)` part) to avoid a compiler error.